# Why does drag go behind target div?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm dragging a div into another div and and clone is going *behind* the target div:
[image]

The HTML is

```
 <div id="widget_area"> 
    <div id="orangeBox" class="widget"> </div>
</div>
<div id="page">
</div>
```

There's a jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/2Xu2P/8/  that shows the HTML, jQuery, and CSS much better than this.  Only included this, because the forum requires some code if you link to a  jsFiddle.

I can fix the problem two ways: remove the widget_area div:

[image]

or remove the position:relative style from the target div:

[image]

Does anyone see what's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define a `z-index` for both containers and make your orange container a higher value.
ie:

```
.widget {
  width:98px;
   height:98px;
   background-color:orange;
   border:1px solid black;
   cursor:pointer;
   z-index: 3; 
}
div#page {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#3a8;
    border:3px solid black;
    position:relative;    
    z-index: 1; 
}
```

here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Xu2P/10/

Comment: Thanks.  I also found that the draggable() options hash has entries for stack and zindex, which both affect the z-index of the clone while it is moving. So I probably could have fixed it with those also.